# Could someone explain Exception: Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR not initialized for dependency

Tags: dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

I'm get this error with a angular 1.0.0 project and I don't know what this means and what should be done. I do not understand the explanation in  link https://github.com/angular/di.dart/wiki/Uninitialized-Module.DEFAULT_REFLECTOR-error

My project declare one dependency in a library that declares a dependency in angular. So my project doesn't have a direct dependency in angular and I can't declare transformers in the **pubspec.yaml** file.

Comment: The 1.0 version is almost impossible to use. What I do:  in my pubspec.yaml I add angular as a dependency and add the transformer, the application now starts, but now the components do no work, they keep failing with **No getter for 'xxx'**, that is because angular is generating some static file mapping the actions to components and is incapable of create this map correctly, also this very disappointed because pub serve must be quit and run in each change for the generation run again.

Comment: Seems to be the same problem like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error when I was using `main() async` - so removing the `async` and going back to the conventional Future-base version was the solution.

I filed an issue report: https://github.com/angular/di.dart/issues/221

Answer (score 0):

Angular now use static generated content. The html files for components are processed during pub install or pub serve

The **pubspec.yaml** file needs something like:

```
transformers:
- angular:
    html_files:
    - web/controllers/error_warning_controller.html
    - web/controllers/http_interceptor_controller.html
    - web/controllers/notify_tray_controller.html
    - web/controllers/notify_desktop.html
    - web/controllers/panel_controller.html
    - web/controllers/window_controller.html
    dart_sdk: /usr/local/opt/dart/libexec
```

Also it not work if you use a library that depends on angular you need a direct dependency for angular transform to work, I work around declaring the dependency twice, one for the library one for the project that use the library.